# first login i am not get details, the next logins i am getting. What is the problem might be?

Tags: ajax, webforms

when am entering with valid login credentials to my page at that time I am missing some button again logout and login at that time my button is coming what is it might be

Comment: Your question need to include a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on your issue.

Comment: This is a question and answer website, not a fortune telling website, please do provide details of your code and more explaination.